# How to fire render when a views collection is reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm just starting to play around with Backbone. I've got a view associated with a collection, and I want to render the view when the collection successfully syncs with the server.

I've managed to get my collection to sync successfully -

```
  var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Backbone.Model,
    url: '/api/cart/lineitem'
  });

  var myCollection = new MyCollection();

  myCollection.fetch({
    success: function() {
      console.log('fetched ' + myCollection.length + ' objects');
    }
  });
```

The console shows that the fetch function works.

However I'm getting some strange behaviour in my view. I can't seem to get the render function to run.

```
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('#mini_cart'),

    cartTpl: _.template($('#miniCartTemplate').html()),

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', console.log('collection reset'));
    },

    render: function(){
      console.log('rendering MyView');
    }

  });

  var myView = new MyView({
    collection: new MyCollection()
  });
```

The console shows that the event fires but it never enters into the `render` method (ie I get the 'collection reset' message but never the 'rendering MyView' message). I don't really understand what's going on (I don't really see how the `reset` event is being fired on my collection at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', console.log('collection reset'));
```

The third paramter of listenTo has to be a function, not a method call (which doesn't return a function). Try to remove this line or just wrap the console.log call into a function like this:

```
 this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', function(){console.log('collection reset');});
```

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand. That's the problem - the event wasn't really being fired at all.

Comment: See why my answer for why.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this method is the most clean one, but I fetch in my router and redirect once the request was done:

```
index: ->
    self = @
    @subscribes.fetch {
        url: "/subscribes/getbyfacebookid/#{self._options.request.user_id}.json",
        success: (data, xhr) ->
            console.log data
            if data.length == 0 then self.dispIndex() else self.social()
        }

dispForm: ->
    self = @
    $("#app div").html ''
    $("#app center").fadeIn 'fast', () ->
        FB.api 'me', (data) ->
            self.view = new Formapp.Views.Subscribes.NewView(data: data, collection: self.subscribes)
            $("#app center").fadeOut 'fast', () ->
                $('#app div').html(self.view.render().el)

dispIndex: ->
    self = @
    @view = new Formapp.Views.Subscribes.IndexView(@_options)
    $("#app center").fadeOut 'fast', () ->
        $('#app div').html(self.view.render().el)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling `fetch` on one instance of your collection and then passing another (new) instance to the view. This means the 'reset' event is never fired on the instance used by the view.

```
 var myView = new MyView({
    collection: myCollection // use the instance you're going to call fetch on
  });
```

Your `console.log` statement is executed as soon as the `render` method is called and not when the 'reset' event is fired. That's why you're seeing that log statement but not the one in the `render` method. What you probably want to do is this:

```
// Pass a function to the listenTo method which will be executed when the event fires
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', function() {
    console.log('collection reset') 
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that was definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a callback:

```
myCollection.on('reset', myView.render);
```

Also consider using a listener from the view

```
myView.listenTo(myCollection, 'reset', this.render)
```